# PHP reset error/exception handler back to native?

Tags: php

I am wondering if there is a way to restore the native PHP handler, I know there is `restore_error_handler` but I am not sure how many `set_error_handlers` could be called.

I read a comment on PHP.net (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php#113517) that says: "If you want to be sure that the native PHP error handler is called without resetting the handler stack (as set_error_handler(null) does), you can simply call set_error_handler with $error_types set to zero. This can be especially use full in conjunction with e.g. error_get_last():"

```
// var_dump or anything else, as this will never be called because of the 0
set_error_handler('var_dump', 0);
@$undef_var;
restore_error_handler();
```

But I am confused by what he means, does he mean that if I call `set_error_handler(null)` it will reset it to native or?

**Edit:** After looking through some PHP source it appears that `set_error_handler(null)` is php 5.5 and above. So that won't work. So I guess back to my original question of how do I reset to native without knowing how many `set_error_handler's` where called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the PHP docs specify, passing `null` to `set_error_handler` was added in PHP 5.5 - [source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php#refsect1-function.set-error-handler-changelog).

As Nicolas's comment from that same page mentions, a workaround is to pass any function as the first argument to `set_error_handler`, and pass `0` as the second argument. As an example:

```
<?php

    // turn on error reporting
    error_reporting(-1);

    // $bar is not set, native PHP error will be thrown
    $foo = $bar;

    // overwrite the error handler a few times
    set_error_handler(function(){ var_dump(1); });
    set_error_handler(function(){ var_dump(2); });
    set_error_handler(function(){ var_dump(3); });

    // $bar is not set, result of var_dump(3), will be shown
    $foo = $bar;

    // restore native handler
    set_error_handler('count', 0);

    // $bar is not set, native PHP error will be thrown
    $foo = $bar;

?>
```